# Magento 2.3.1 Getting Incompatible argument type error

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3

I'm getting the following error: `Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper. Actual type: array`.

I have tried changing the parent constructor, but I'm still getting the same error.

I also tried extending:

```
extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
```

still, getting the same error.

posting the relevant part of my code:

```
class ProductList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_categoryRepository;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_filterBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magefan\Blog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    //    parent::_construct();
    //    parent::__construct($context, $data);
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }
```

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Update the file calling $postDataHelper

```
class ProductList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
protected $_logger;
protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
protected $_productRepository;
protected $_categoryRepository;
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_filterBuilder;
protected $_postDataHelper,


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magefan\Blog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
 parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
}
```

> rm -rf var/cache/ *var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/
>   *pub/static/* generated/*

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you please explain, what do you mean: "Update the file calling $postDataHelper"?

Comment: you have missed this part https://cl.ly/5d96f284c5e4

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: you need to run the command i showed you , also *bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy* , you might declare $layerResolver .

Comment: Is your issue fixed ?

Comment: no, same problem